# how to write rspec for ability using cancancan

Tags: rspec-rails, cancancan

I have a implemented the post and user model where post model belongs to user model. I defined the ability model for authorisation so that only user who created the post can able to delete or update the post. i have the post controller like this:

```
def edit
  @post = @topic.posts.find(params[:id])
  authorize! :update, @post
end
```

Ability model:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :update, Post do |p|
      p.user == user
    end

    can :destroy, Post do |p|
      p.user == user
    end

    can :destroy, Comment do |c|
      c.user == user
    end

    can :create, Post
    can :create, Comment
  end
end
```

What will be the rspec for the above model?
Error:

```html
expected #<User id: nil, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> to respond to `able_to?`

  0) User Check for Abilities What User can do should be able to :create and #<Post id: nil, title: nil, body: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, topic_id: nil, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, user_id: nil>
     Failure/Error: it { should be_able_to(:create, Post.new) }
       expected #<User id: nil, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> to respond to `able_to?`
     # ./spec/models/ability_spec.rb:8:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

expected #<User id: nil, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> to respond to `able_to?`

  0) User Check for Abilities What User can do should be able to :update and #<Post id: nil, title: nil, body: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, topic_id: nil, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, user_id: nil>
     Failure/Error: it { should be_able_to(:update, Post.new) }
       expected #<User id: nil, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> to respond to `able_to?`
     # ./spec/models/ability_spec.rb:9:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the limited information you have provided, I'm going to share a sample `spec` which tests abilities.

```
describe "User" do
    describe "Check for Abilities" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

        describe "What User can do" do
            it { should be_able_to(:create, Post.new) }
            it { should be_able_to(:update, Post.new) }
        end
    end
end
```

What I have provided at the top was a Sample, using which you have to build upon it. My updated answer

```
require "cancan/matchers"

describe "User" do
  describe "abilities" do
    user = User.create!
    ability = Ability.new(user)
    expect(ability).to be_able_to(:create, Post.new)
    expect(ability).to_not be_able_to(:destroy, Post.new)
  end
end
```

Comment: Do u need any further clarification about this question

Comment: For the question you have asked originally, the above is how you test it.

Comment: What error ? Can you update your question with the errors ?

Comment: How to use this same case using expect

Comment: `expect(ability).to be_able_to(:create, Post.new)`

Comment: I got the answer.

Comment: Could you help me in how to write rspec for filtering post based on specified date range??

Comment: I will post another question for that

Comment: Sure. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Okay, I ll post a new question

Comment: I have posted a new question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179511/discussion-between-praveen-r-and-kedarnag-mukanahallipatna).

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52196925/how-to-write-rspec-for-filtering-the-posts-based-on-specified-date-range?noredirect=1#comment91343667_52196925] pleace look this question

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by refactoring your ability file a little bit. Is always a good idea to use a [hash of conditions](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities#hash-of-conditions), rather than blocks. Therefore your ability file should look like:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can [:update, :destroy], Post, user_id: user.id
    can :destroy, Comment, user_id: user.id
    can :create, Post
    can :create, Comment
  end
end
```

this is a shorter version of the one you have, and it does more.

Here is an example on how I would write the test, based on the [cancancan documentation](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Testing-Abilities):

```
require 'cancan/matchers'
RSpec.describe Ability do  
  subject(:ability) { described_class.new(user) }

  context 'when there is no user' do
    let(:user){ nil }

    it { is_expected.to_not be_able_to(:create, Post)
    ....
  end

  context 'when the user is present' do
    let(:user){ User.new }

    it { is_expected.to be_able_to(:create, Post) }
    ...
end
```

end
end

I let the rest of the tests to you.