# How to write rspec for filtering the posts based on specified date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a simple blog application where the user can able to filter the post based on the date range (start_date & end_date).I have used AJAX call for displaying the post in the index page. Once the user give the range of date using two date pickers and click on submit button the AJAX call is made and the filtered posts will be displayed.There is no problem in the development side but in case of testing I dont know how to proceed further.But my objective is to check weather the posts displayed in the index page are within the specified date range. I have included the datefilter action defined in the post controllers:

```html
def dateFilter
    if (params[:start_date].present? )&& (params[:end_date].present?)
      if Time.parse(params[:start_date])<=Time.parse(params[:end_date])&& (Time.parse(params[:start_date])<= Date.today)&& (Time.parse(params[:end_date])<= Date.today)
        @start_date= params[:start_date].to_date.beginning_of_day
        @end_date=params[:end_date].to_date.end_of_day
      else
        @error = true
      end
    else
      @start_date= Date.yesterday.beginning_of_day
      @end_date=Date.today.end_of_day
    end
    @posts= Post.date_filter(@start_date,@end_date)
  end
```

In the index page I have used the datepicker as follows:

```html
 <%= form_tag({:controller => 'posts', :action => 'dateFilter'},remote: true) do %>
    <%=  date_field_tag 'start_date' %>
    <%=  date_field_tag 'end_date' %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

when the AJAX call is made it renders the posts as a js file datefilter.js.erb

```html
<% if @error==true %>
alert("enter correct date format");
<% elsif @posts.blank? %>
alert("No posts in the given date");
<%else %>
$('.post_div').html('<%= j render @posts %>')
<% end %>
$('#page').hide()
```

Help me in writing rspec for the above scenario

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I need to write only controller spec

Comment: What is stopping you? See the [guide](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs) and follow.

Comment: I have already seen it. In this scenario I need to create several posts during the testing and I need to give the start_date and end_date and check weather the returned posts are within my range

Comment: Yes, and which part is troubling you in particular? Is it "creating multiple posts", "passing params to the action", or "inspecting the filtered posts"?

Comment: I am completely blank how to proceed

Comment: Do you have [`rspec-rails`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) installed?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I already have that and I have return many test caes for other features. But in this case i am blank

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple posts using before action with specified dates and call the controller action with a date range you know to have specified number of posts and check the count of the expected posts in the response

For example

```
@post1 = FactoryBot.create(:post, start_date: DATE) 
@post2 = FactoryBot.create(:post, start_date: DATE) //Using Factory

let(:data) = {
start_date: Date,
end_date: Date}

get:CONTROLLER_ACTION params: data
```

Then expect the response as per your requirement

Comment: I tried it but how  to send the params in the test to the controller action please update your answer to my case for getting start_date and end_date

Comment: U can send params as specified above in the spec file. to check start and end date depends on how you return data from that controller action can you please specify it